# Posts, tags and mongoose in Express JS - or any other language for that matter

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, tags

I'm trying to figure out the best approach for tagging posts in my express application. There are two types of post, say 'Phones' and 'Tablets'. They both can share tags but require different Models to access them (this wont change).

I opened up Wordpress to see how it handles tags, but there is a lot of replica data in the DB and I don't feel this is right for my application.

Should I store tags as a String with a delimiter and query it within the post? Or should I create a new table for those tags that has a post ID associated with the list of tags so that when I search I only have to search that given table, rather than two different ones?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as document will not exceed 16MB I will keep tags inside a document as an array field.

Then I will create an index on tags field - to have an easy way to display documents containing specific tag (mongo will index all array entries and provide fast search).

Comment: @connor leech could you be more specific?

Comment: what would a schema look like for Post and Tags in mongoose where post has many tags and tags has many posts?